# How to make api call for the fetching user email using facebook sdk 4.0in android

Tags: android, email, facebook-sdk-4.0

Trying to fetch facebook user profile info including user email,I have tried and succeed in getting required info except email address,as per developer page i have to make new api request to get email and location details,Someone suggest me how to make this api request in the following code 
this is how i am making request to get facebook user profile data

```
// Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code

                    // login ok get access token
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {

                                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                                        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
                                        FacebookSdk
                                                .addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

                                        System.out
                                                .println("AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()"
                                                        + AccessToken
                                                                .getCurrentAccessToken()
                                                                .toString());
                                        Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId();
                                        Profile.getCurrentProfile().getFirstName();
                                        Profile.getCurrentProfile().getLastName();
                                        Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(50, 50);

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters
                            .putString("fields",
                                    "id,firstName,lastName,name,email,gender,birthday,address");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);

                    request.executeAsync();

                    Intent loginintent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            EditProfile.class);
                    startActivity(loginintent);
                    System.out.println("XXXX " + getId());

                    makeJsonObjReq();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
            });

    return view;

}
```

this is suggestion given by [developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) to get email how to call api in my code,please help

Answer (score 0):

Hop this will work for you.

```
final Request request = Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(final GraphUser use, final Response response) {
                final String email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
            }
        });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

new graph api to get user info in v2.3

```
new Request(session,"/{user-id}",null,HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback(){
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
}).executeAsync();
```

Comment: The method executeBatchAsync(GraphRequest) is undefined for the type Request and  Session cannot be resolved and Request.GraphUserCallback cannot be resolved to a type and The method executeBatchAsync(GraphRequest) is undefined for the type Request

Comment: You should import all class from facebook sdk.
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;

Comment: yes,yes I have tried all but no luck means these packages are not importing which facebook sdk you are using?

Comment: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0+

Comment: I have implemented 3.5 recently but now i want to use 4.0 ,I think few classes may deprecated from old sdk ,This facebook sdk integration became to hectic due to several updates

Comment: yes you are right. look's like i have to start from beginning.

Comment: i have update may answer. this will help to get user email address.